# How to handle setting up environment in makefile?

Tags: makefile

So, to compile my executable, I need to have the library locations set up correctly. The problem is, the setup comes from a bunch of scripts that do the env variable exporting, and what needs to be set up may change (beyond my control) so I need to use those scripts instead of copying their functionality. To compile in regular command line, I need to do something like:

```
setup library1
setup library2
source some_other_setup_script.bash
g++ blah.c
# setup is a executable on my system that run some scripts
```

How would I write a makefile that accomplishes that? As far as I tried, the env variable exporting does not carry over (i.e. "export VAR=remember; echo $VAR" won't work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If variable exporting is not working the way it does on your command line, that suggests that Make is choosing a shell different from the one you're using, with different syntax for handling variables (`export VAR=remember; echo $VAR` works fine for me). Make uses `/bin/sh` by default, but you can override this with the SHELL variable, which Make does *not* import from the environment. I suggest setting SHELL (in the Makefile) to whatever you're using in your environment and trying the `export VAR=remember` experiment again.

Comment: I also realize that I should use $$VAR so that make won't think that I'm quoting a macro...

Comment: It doesn't really mean that. GNU make simply runs a new shell for each line in the comand. (I suspect he combined the two commands with ; for brevity)
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution
"When it is time to execute commands to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new subshell for each command line."

Comment: would be great if you can share the way to set `SHELL` in `Makefile` right here too

Comment: @cryanbhu: Looking back after ten years, I wish I'd given a slightly different Answer, but don't feel like editing it. Anyway, to set `SHELL`, just put `SHELL=/bin/bash` in your makefile (*outside* any rule). Be sure to use the actual path in use on your system; if you're not sure, try `which bash`, or whatever the command is in whichever system you're using.

Answer (score 11):

You can also add environment variables properly with the machinery of GNU make, like so:

```
export TEST:="Something Good!"
test:
    echo $$TEST
```

This (I think) has different semantics from:

```
TEST2:="Something not quite so useful?"
test2:
    echo ${TEST2}
```

Which (again, I think) does the substitution within make before passing along to the shell. Note that the export command doesn't work within a target block, just unindented as an immediately executed command.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you will need to define the variable and execute the compiler in a shell list or even a script, rather than in separate `make` commands. There are a couple of refinements you could add, however. You could tell `make` about the script:

```
maintarget: script.sh blah.c
    source script.sh; g++ blah.c

script.sh:
    setup include script here
```

Another thing would be to just execute all that stuff in the same shell

```
maintarget: blah.c
    run this; run that; run the other thing; g++ blah.c
```

I believe all `make` versions will run a `;` list in the same shell, but you can always force a subshell with `(list)` or by calling specifically a shell script as a compiler command wrapper.

Don't forget to have the appropriate targets depend on your scripts themselves. BTW, some `make` versions (`pmake` aka `bsd make`) can execute a command when defining a make variable, and all versions of `make` then exports those. But I don't think `gmake` can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could write another shell script that executes all those commands, then prints out variable assignments that make can use. Run the script, pipe its output to a file, then include that file from your Makefile. For example:

Makefile:

```
all:
    echo $(FOO)

test.mk: test.sh
    ./$< > $@

include test.mk
```

test.sh

```
echo "FOO=1"
```

Running "make" in the directory containing this Makefile produces:

```
make: Entering directory `/home/luser/build/mktest'
Makefile:7: test.mk: No such file or directory
./test.sh > test.mk
make: Leaving directory `/home/luser/build/mktest'
make: Entering directory `/home/luser/build/mktest'
echo 1
1
make: Leaving directory `/home/luser/build/mktest'
```

make creates test.mk by running the shell script, then includes it. test.mk contains the output of test.sh, and is parsed as a Makefile. See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include for more details.

We use a variant of this in Mozilla's client.mk to let you define options in a "mozconfig" file:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/client.mk#138

Answer (score 0):

Restatement: How do I get a shell variable into a make file?

Something like:

```
MYVAR := $(shell echo $(MYVAR)) <any_makefile_additions_here>
```

So, this defines MYVAR inside a MAKEFILE when an environment variable named MYVAR is also set.

Answer (score 0):

It might be of interest, that, in order to override an option that is already defined in a makefile, `make` supports (I am referring to GNU Make 3.82, but other version probably too) the option `-e`.
Example:

Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
...
```

Run make:

```
CC=gcc-4.7
make -e
```

will use gcc-4.7 instead of gcc.